# Neural network activation

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, classification, perception

From this [site](http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/Neural/single.neural.html),

The output node has a "threshold" t.

Rule:

```
If summed input ≥ t, then it "fires" (output y = 1). 
Else (summed input < t) it doesn't fire (output y = 0).
```

How y equals to `zero`. Any Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural networks have a so called "activation function", it's usually some form of a sigmoid-like function to map the inputs into separate outputs.

http://zephyr.ucd.ie/mediawiki/images/b/b6/Sigmoid.png

For you it happens to be either 0 or 1 and using a comparison instead of a sigmoid function,
so your activation curve will be even sharper than the graph above. In the said graph, your `t`, the threshold, is 0 on the X axis.

So as pseudo code :

`sum = w1 * I1 + w2 + I2 + ... + wn * In`

`sum` is the weighted sum of all in the inputs the neuron, now all you have to do is compare that sum to `t`, the threshold :

```
if sum >= t then y = 1      // Your neuron is activated
else y = 0
```

You can use the last neuron's output as the networks output to predict something into 1/0, true/false etc.

If you're studying NNs, I'd suggest you start with the XOR problem, then it will all make sense.